Running different Junit5 Cucumber tests-suites with duplicate step definitions
I have two domain specific junit5 platform cucumber test suites.
A:
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectPackages("de.bla.blubb1")
@SelectClasspathResource("de/bla/blubb1")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "de.bla.blubb1")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty,json:target/blubb1cucumber.json")
public class RunBlubb1CucumberTest
{
    // nichts zu tun
}

and B:
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectPackages("de.bla.blubb2")
@SelectClasspathResource("de/bla/blubb2")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "de.bla.blubb2")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty,json:target/blubb2cucumber.json")
public class RunBlubb2CucumberTest
{
    // nichts zu tun
}

The stepdefiniton classes are in the same package as each of the suite-classes.
In both stepdefintions classes are some duplicate step definitions (just the method body is different) and used in the feature files.
    @Gegebensei("Example")
    public void gegebenSeiExample(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map)
    {
        for (Entry<String, Map<String, String>> e : map.entrySet())
        {
            blabla.put(e.getKey(), new BlaMock(e.getValue()));
        }
    }

If i run both in intellij idea by selecting just both suite classes, all tests run succesful. If i run all tests i get duplicate step execptions. (also in eclipse)
DuplicateStepDefinitionException


io.cucumber.core.runner.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in de.bla.blubb1.StepDefsEingangsparameter.erstelle() and de.bla.blubb2.StepDefsEingangsparameter.erstelle()

    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.lambda$prepareGlue$3(CachingGlue.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CachingGlue.prepareGlue(CachingGlue.java:272)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:72)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$4(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:112)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:109)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.NodeDescriptor$PickleDescriptor.execute(NodeDescriptor.java:168)
    at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.NodeDescriptor$PickleDescriptor.execute(NodeDescriptor.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

I already tried a lot with forking on a class basis (in the run configuration) but this slows the other tests way too much down and other stuff.
The step definitions should stay as they are (requirement). I know i could just rename them.
Is there a way to run those two suites "separately"?
(without to change maven config and run config)
I only want those two cucumber suite-classes to run separately (in diffrent threads? jvms?), preferably defined with an annotation or configuration property somewhere.

What is in stack trace with the duplicate step exception?

@M.P.Korstanje added it.

Cheers. This starts to sound like a bug, can you reproduce this minimally by using https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton ?

edit: It starts to sound like a bug because I would expect both suites to run without duplicate step definition exceptions. As currently described it should just work.

Add the parallel thread configuration in maven-surefire-plugin
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>2</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Also create 2 suites in TestNG file
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suites>
    <!-- Suite 1 -->
    <suite name="Suite A">
        <test name="Test A1">
            <classes>
                <class name="de.bla.blubb1.RunBlubb1CucumberTest"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>

    <!-- Suite 2 -->
    <suite name="Suite B">
        <test name="Test B1">
            <classes>
                <class name="de.bla.blubb2.RunBlubb2CucumberTest"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
</suites>


Hi, thanks. But I preferably want a solution without explicit forking in maven.
